# array last element is not get printed

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which is getting some id's form db table (which are 5 id's) and then i have to fetch more data based on these id's. i got data against each id except last one number 5. 
i don't know what the problem is. any kind of help

here is my piece of code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
    {
        $qry_to_find_section_id = "SELECT DISTINCT sc.sectionID as SectionID FROM scoreanalysis as sc WHERE  sc.formatID =43 and sc.waveID = 29 and sc.territoryID = '".$locations_id_arr[$i]."'";

        $qry_to_find_section_id_rs = mysql_query($qry_to_find_section_id) or  die($qry_to_find_section_id."<br><br>".mysql_error                                             ());
        $section_id_arr= array();
        while($rs_section_id = mysql_fetch_array($qry_to_find_section_id_rs))
            {
                $section_id_arr [] = $rs_section_id['SectionID'];
            }

        $count_section_id = count($section_id_arr);
        for($j=0; $j<$count_section_id; $j++)
            {
                echo $section_id_arr[$j].' ';
            }   echo '<br>';

    }
```

Comment: your code is correct may be your last index has blank value

Comment: No when i manually put this query in phpMyadmin it is working and it has a value!

Comment: Check this. '$j<=$count_section_id'

Comment: `$count_section_id` should be `count($section_id_arr) - 1;`. Because your array index starts at **`0`**. **EDIT:** Please show what the array looks like, just to clarify.

Comment: @Ghost i have already tried that but not working

Comment: Should I be the one to point out that mysql_* functions are deprecated. If you are building something new right now, you should switch to mysqli. Deprecated meaning that those functions will cease to exist in the near future, which means your code will stop working for newer versions of PHP ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

**OUTER LOOP**

> ```
>     $count = count($locations)-1;
>     for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++)
>         {
>             // inner code
>         }
> ```

**INNER LOOP**

> ```
>     $count_section_id = count($section_id_arr)-1;
>     for($j=0; $j<=$count_section_id; $j++)
>         {
>             echo $section_id_arr[$j].' ';
>         }
> ```

**[here is a link](http://ideone.com/Jz73gU)**

Comment: No change Same result :(

Comment: What is the outer `for` loop for? What do you loop through?

Comment: what i want to do is i have a locations table and sections table .. each locations has more than one section .. i get values form location tables against a project and store into an arrray then based on this array i get sections.
and what the problem is locations array got five values.. and against each location i got 6 values .. my output looks like this 
143 144 145 146 147 148 
143 144 145 146 147 148 
143 144 145 146 147 148 
143 144 145 146 147 148 

while it should be like five rows

and outer loop is for locations as i did
 $count = count($locations_id_arr);

Comment: So if you try what I said above with the outer loop. e.g. 
`$count = count($locations)-1;` and run it thtough the for as
`for ($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++)`
Meaning that possibly you are coming up 1 short on the outer loop rather than the innner loop

Comment: it worked now thank you but could you please tell me what is the purpose to use -1 ??

Comment: the actual count of the number of items in you array is 5, but the for loop counts through the array starting at the first element which is element[0]. 
so as a counter you will count 0,1,2,3,4 to access the 5 elements you where after. 
makes it more readable i guess, but looking at it, it would not have made a difference to your request.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct.

Are you sure that you are making exactly the same query on exactly the same database using phpMyAdmin?
Try adding a row through phpMyAdmin that should show up in PHP output and see if the problem really is "array last element not printed" or is it actually "something completely else but very similar is printed".

Answer (score -2):

First you should check your $section_id_arr array

**print_r($section_id_arr)**

Comment: Please expand on this as it doesn't attempt to answer the question at hand.

Comment: it is returning same result excluding 5th record

Comment: oh.. then the problem with sql query. or the fifth data is not access with where condition used in query

Comment: what i actully want to do is taking an array of id's againts specific values and when we get that array i have to find other values in some other table based on first array .. what i should get is 5 rows with values 143 144 145 146 147 148 but i got 4 ...5th is missing

Comment: @SiddiqueAboobacker when i check manaully in phpMyadmin is has data against each row

Comment: Why you use the first for loop

for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)

can you change your query to

$locations = implode(",",$locations_id_arr);
$qry_to_find_section_id = "SELECT DISTINCT sc.sectionID as SectionID FROM scoreanalysis as sc WHERE  sc.formatID =43 and sc.waveID = 29 and sc.territoryID in(".$locations.")";

Comment: @SiddiqueAboobacker what i want to do is i have a locations table and sections table .. each locations has more than one section .. i get values form location tables against a project and store into an arrray then based on this array i get sections. and what the problem is locations array got five values.. and against each location i got 6 values .. my output looks like this 143 144 145 146 147 148 143 144 145 146 147 148 143 144 145 146 147 148 143 144 145 146 147 148 while it should be like five rows and outer loop is for locations as i did $count = count($locations_id_arr);

Comment: @SiddiqueAboobacker yeah it worked. Thanks a lot but could you tell me why i have to use this?